# get all the combinations of 10 factor variables

Tags: r

I have 10 factor variables, i want to get all the possible unique combinations of the factor variables by level wise.

My dataframe has the following data variables:

[image: data vars]

And i want to get the output as formatted below:

[image: Output]

Comment: aggregate(dt[,-c(1)],list(Pass = Pass,college_Grade = college_Grade), length)

Comment: Check table and prop.table functon.

Comment: Thanks for editing, there is a typo mistake is Prob=0 and Prob=1, that is actually by Pass variable Pass=0 and Pass=1

Answer (score 0):

```
unique(dataframe_name)
```

This command will display unique values in dataframe.

```
unique_data <- subset(unique(dataframe_name))
```

Comment: I am looking for levelwise combinations by variablewise. ex: College grade is my variable and it has levels 1,2,3 and qualification has 3 levels Undergraduate, Masters and Phd. so i want the combibation on them.